# Is it possible to do client side logging of downloaded HTML code?

Tags: logging, client-side

I'm trying to find a way to log HTML downloaded onto someone's machine, may be a plugin, may be a stand-alone program.

We have customers reporting popups from advertisers that we don't get. Most likely it's a geo-targeted script responsible for this. We want to filter out these advertisers obviously and ban them from our site. It's hard to find the responsible party without being able to replicate the problem and people reporting the problem usually have not enough technical skills to be able to figure out who's responsible. I want to be able to offer them a plugin or something that logs the downloaded HTML until the problem arises again at which point they send me their logs and it would be easy to know where the problem came from.